# Questions regarding Visual C++ compiler

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have studied C language with TC++ compiler and now I want to do C data structure programming using Visual C++ 2008 Express compiler. As I know code compiled under Visual C++ produces intermediate code which can be processed at runtime by the CLR. But also native code can be produced by VC++ using win32 option. Am I correct? And I also have following questions:

1. In my data structure book there are programs which are console programs but using **windows.h** header file. Do I need windows.h header file in Visual C++ win32 console application (C program)?
2. Can I create a Windows Forms application without CLR? In WIN32 templates (VC++ 2008 Express) there is no option for Windows Forms application.
3. It is given in many websites that all Windows applications must include windows.h header file. If I write win32 console program (C, not C++) then is it also a Windows application? Why and when to use windows.h ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* to include `windows.h` for console applications, but of course you will not be able to use any Windows API functions if you don't. It's perfectly possible to write a console program without them though.

You cannot create a Windows Forms app without depending on the CLR; Forms is a .NET technology.

You must include `windows.h` if you want to access the Windows API. All applications that have a windowed UI need this; most console applications don't.

Comment: thank you for your answer. could you please tell me What are Windows API functions?

Comment: so can I conclude that all Visual C++ applications(including console application)are windows application but not all windows applications need windows.h header file and it is wrong :"all Windows applications must include windows.h header file".

Comment: @TanmoyBanerjee: It depends on what "windows applications" means for you. If it means "applications running on a Windows OS" then obviously all of them are. If it means "applications that create one or more windows using `CreateWindow` or `CreateWindowEx`" then obviously console applications are not. If it means "using any function of the Windows API" then console applications may or may not be windows applications.

Comment: :what does "windows application" simply mean?

Comment: @TanmoyBanerjee: My whole point is that there is no *single* technical definition of what a "windows application" is.

Comment: Thank you Jon..I have got it now.

Answer (score 0):

> In my data structure book there are programs which are console programs but using header file. do i need windows.h header file in Visual C++ win32 console application(C program)?

`windows.h` is recommended to include for many functions like `CreateFile` etc even though they are not declared there. That's windows/VC++ convention.

> Can i create a windows form application without CLR ? in WIN32 templates(VC++ 2008 express) there is no option for Windows form application.

May be you can try MFC, but that seems to be out dated now.

> It is given in many websites that all windows application must include windows.h header file.If I write win32 console program(C, not C++) then is it also a windows application? why and when to use windows.h ?

Look at answer for #1